# any module for gtag.js for angular js

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

is there any module is available for gtag.js. and how could i add event for hyperlink.

```
 <a ui-sref="ResetPassword">reset your password</a>

gtag('event', 'reset', {
  'event_category': 'reset',
  'event_action': 'Click',
  'event_label': 'Reset'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<a ng-click="ResetPassword()">reset your password</a>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.ResetPassword = function(){

    //send event here
     gtag('event', 'reset', {
       'event_category': 'reset',
       'event_action': 'Click',
       'event_label': 'Reset'
     }); 

     $state.go('//path here');
}
```